# Is there any way to force Readability to work with Stack Overflow?

Tags: stack-overflow

I noticed Readability doesn't work with Stack Overflow - clicking `Read Now` bookmarklet doesn't have any effect on Stack Overflow's pages. What's the reason? Is there any way to force Readability to work with Stack Overflow?

One of the pages I was trying to run Readability on is [What algorithm does Readability use for extracting text from URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3652657/95735)

Comment: yeah I would like to know this too

Comment: You could contact them http://www.readability.com/contact about having issues with reading S.O. articles

Comment: [Readability shut down permanently on September 30, 2016](https://medium.com/@readability/the-readability-bookmarking-service-will-shut-down-on-september-30-2016-1641cc18e02b#.fhop5yby1)